# Graceful shutdown in IHostedService in asp.net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got a problem with my asp net core api project. I try to implement some basic checks (for example db-connectivity) and if the check fails, I want to graceful shutdown my application.
For that, I implement the interface `IHostedService` and add it as a hostedService within the `ConfigureServices` method of my `startup` class (`services.AddHostedService<MyService>();`).

The `StartAsync` implementation of MyService looks currently like that:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
}
```

And the variable `applicationLifetime` is of type `IHostApplicationLifetime` and is injected from the DI-Service. I get the following exception:

```
[15:58:42 FTL] Unable to start Kestrel.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 31
   atProgram.<Main>(String[] args)
```

and line 31 of my Programm.cs class is part of the main method with `await host.RunAsync();`

My goal is to stop the application before other hostedServices run or the api can handle requests.

Comment: Please, share a [mcve]